# Call limit exceeds while implementing DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

While implementing the **DocuSign** we are getting `The maximum number of hourly API invocations has been exceeded` error message sometimes this is because of the API call rate exceed per 1 hour. Anyone have any idea how to increase the API call rate per account from 1000 to 5000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to contact your DocuSign's Account Manager with a valid usecase why you need the API limit to be increased to 5000. As a defensive check you should always read the header in the API response, DocuSign provide the data as whats your call limit, how many calls are remaining and what is next schedule counter reset for you. By reading these header values, you can make your application pause for sometime so that you don't hit threshold limit and handle the limit scenario properly.

Along with your DocuSign Account Manager, you can contact support@docusign.com also.